# MacBook has started shutting down when at 5% battery

Tags: macbook, sleep, battery-life, battery

This is new, just started this month:

- Usually it would last until 0%. For a few days it had been shutting off at around 4%. Last night it shut off at 5%... really hope tomorrow night it's not 6% and so on :/
- It doesn't just go to sleep when this happens, it actually shuts off.
- I bought this MacBook around August, 2008.
- My battery is OK according to system profiler. And its health is at 85% according to iStat Pro widget. It's at 703 cycles and 3 years of using it 24/7 as my main computer.
- OS 10.6.8, all up to date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Battery metering simply isn't that accurate for the battery controller to be able to reliably tell 5% from nearly dead.  Likely your battery is showing its age and it goes from a charge state that "looks like" 5% to being dead fairly rapidly.

You can try disconnecting/reconnecting the battery -- this sometimes "resets" the battery metering circuitry.  But I'd recommend that you set your controls (if you can) to hibernate or whatever at 10% or above.

Comment: It's at 703 cycles and 3 years of using it 24/7 as my main computer. Maybe it's just age. But why is it shutting down? — Sidenote: is it better to leave it plugged in all day, or to charge it to 100% and then disconnect until it goes to 0%?

Comment: 703 cycles is a lot. You've already gotten very far with this one.

Answer (score 0):

Try taking your battery out and putting it back in if it happens again. Then check the system preferences to make sure everything is unchecked.

Comment: To make sure all of what is unchecked?

Comment: *> check the system preferences to make sure everything is unchecked*. How does that make sense at all? Which system preferences? In OS X energy saving preferences, there are only: 1) Put hard disks to sleep (> irrelevant), 2) Wake for network access (> irrelevant), 3) Automatically reduce brightness (> irrelevant). /cc @nhinkle

Comment: I agree @slhck, it's confusing. Let's see if he comments to clarify what he meant, and if not, we can just remove the answer.

Comment: well you don't have to remove any answer the battery and energy settings

Comment: What exactly in the battery and energy settings? I mentioned all there is, you don't need to uncheck those as they are irrelevant to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

How long has it been since you [calibrated your battery](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1490)?  It may just need to tweak it's measurements of full-charge and functionally-empty.